# Diffraction of rays

Tags: energy, visible-light, diffraction

To all the physics experts here this might sound like a stupid question, but I give it a try:

This is a sketch of how you usually learn about the effect of diffraction in an experiment:

[image]

Now I was asking myself for a long time: Those two rays that cancel each other do have a certain energy.

For regular rays that hit the screen, you could see their energy in the form of light, as they were reflected to your eyes and all other directions.

But now, where is the energy of the rays that cancel each other? Energy cannot vanish, so it must have transformed in some way, but this is only an assumption of mine.

*Where is the energy of two rays that cancelled each other during the effect of diffraction?*

Comment: This answer to another question may be helpful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/single-photon-and-double-slit-experiment/35835#35835

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158105/can-the-intensity-distribution-behind-edges-and-slits-be-explaint-by-the-interac

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114384/relationship-between-material-and-fringes-behind-an-edge